# How to compress enterprise geodatabase with stored procedure?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I'm looking for a stored procedure in ArcSDE for SQL Server which performs geodatabase compression to include it in our daily maintenance plan. Is there any such thing in ArcSDE 10.0?

Comment: Is using a Stored Procedure critical or would using ArcPy.Compress_management (new at 10.1 I think) work? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003t6000000

Comment: No, I'm just curious. I now that I can use sdeversion.exe or python script to achieve this. But I just want to store all maintenance steps in one place (SQL server maintenance plan)